# I want to display products from my database to HTML. I only get the last row from my database to show up

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I am working on a school project, a simple webshop.
I decided to ask it here.

What i want to do is display products from my database to my "product page" using PHP.

For some reason i only get the last product to show, also having trouble with the images.. I know the query is correct.

"SELECT * FROM products";

Here is my code.

This is my PHP, I have put this on top of the product.php page.

```
product.php
<?php
 session_start();
 include "includes/connectie.php";
 include "includes/navbar.php";

 $vraag = "SELECT * FROM products";
 //var_dump($vraag); Var dump test

 $resultaat = $conn->query($vraag);

 if ($resultaat->num_rows > 0) 
 {   // Min. 1 row returned

     while ($rij = $resultaat->fetch_assoc())
     {
        $id = $rij['id'];
        $titel = $rij['product_name'];
        $prijs = $rij['product_price'];
        $omschrijving = $rij['description'];
        $foto = $rij['image'];
      } 
 }
 else 
 {
    // Do nothing
 }
?>
```

This is my HTML code below, where i want to "display" i also have this in the same file as code above. So first php, then html

```
product.php

<body>
  <div class="products">
    <div class="productContainer">
      <h1 id="banner">ALL ITEMS</h1>
      <div class="productRow">
        <?php
            echo '<img src="img/product_'.$id.'.jpg">';
        ?>
      </div>
        <?php 
            echo '<h1>'.$titel.'</h1>';
            echo '<p class="prijs">'.$prijs.'</p>'; 
            echo '<p class="omschrijving">'.$omschrijving.'</p>';
        ?>

        <div class="productRow">
        <?php
            echo '<img src="product_'.$id.'.jpg">';
            echo '<h1>'.$titel.'</h1>';
            echo '<p class="prijs">'.$prijs.'</p>'; 
            echo '<p class="omschrijving">'.$omschrijving.'</p>';
        ?>
```

So i only put the HTML/PHP where i would want the first two products as example.
In total i have 6 products. I also included a picture of the database

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXFhx.png)

What am i doing wrong?

This is how it looks right now:
[example of product display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqUqh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your php file you have added all the values from database to an array. but you have not used any loop when you are trying to display array values in html. loop is a must to display all the values of array. Add a loop in your HTML file.

Comment: Okay!! I followed the instructions from my school presentation directly, i will try and work this with your advice! Thanks very very much!